# Read Time Out Exception in Cassandra using cassandra-driver-core

Tags: mysql, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am writing a Java application which reads the data from MySQL and stores it in Cassandra as Sqoop does not support a direct import to Cassandra. I am using Producer-Consumer framework to achieve the same due to high number of records (in millions) in MySQL. But I am getting ReadTimeOut Exception (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during read). I have one Producer class which reads the data from MySQL and puts it into one queue. There is one consumer class which reads the data from that queue and pushes it to Cassndra. There is one manager class which acts as a coordination bridge between these two classes.
Producer class :-

```
public class MySQLPrintJobProducer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<PrintJobDAO> printerJobQueue = null;
    private Connection conn = null;
    public MySQLPrintJobProducer(BlockingQueue<PrintJobDAO> printerJobQueue) throws MySQLClientException {
        this.printerJobQueue = printerJobQueue;     
        connect();
    }

    private void connect() throws MySQLClientException {
        try {
            Class.forName(MySQLClientConstants.MYSQL_JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysqlserverhose/mysqldb?user=mysqluser&password=mysqlpasswd");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new MySQLClientException(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new MySQLClientException(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // Get total number of print jobs stored.
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(MySQLClientConstants.PRINT_JOB_COUNT_QUERY);
            int totalPrintJobs = 0;
            if(rs != null) {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    totalPrintJobs = rs.getInt(1);
                }
            }
            // Determine the number of iterations.
            int rowOffset = 1;
            int totalIteration = ((totalPrintJobs / ExportManagerConstants.DATA_TRANSFER_BATCH_SIZE) + 1);
            pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(MySQLClientConstants.PRINT_JOB_FETCH_QUERY);
            int totalRecordsFetched = 0;
            // Iterate over to fetch Print Job Records in bathces and put it into the queue.
            for(int i = 1; i <= totalIteration; i++) {                              
                pStmt.setInt(1, rowOffset);
                pStmt.setInt(2, ExportManagerConstants.DATA_TRANSFER_BATCH_SIZE);
                System.out.println("In iteration : " + i + ", Row Offset : " + rowOffset);
                rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
                synchronized (this.printerJobQueue) {
                    if(this.printerJobQueue.remainingCapacity() > 0) {
                        while(rs.next()) {
                            totalRecordsFetched = rs.getRow();
                            printerJobQueue.offer(new PrintJobDAO(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2),   rs.getString(3), rs.getDate(4), 
                                rs.getTimestamp(5), rs.getInt(6), rs.getInt(7), rs.getInt(8), rs.getInt(9), 
                                rs.getInt(10), rs.getFloat(11), rs.getFloat(12), rs.getInt(13), rs.getFloat(14), rs.getInt(15), 
                                rs.getDouble(16), rs.getDouble(17), rs.getDouble(18), rs.getDouble(19), rs.getDouble(20), 
                                rs.getFloat(21)));
                            this.printerJobQueue.notifyAll();
                        }
                        System.out.println("In iteration : " + i + ", Records Fetched : " + totalRecordsFetched + 
                                ", Queue Size : " + printerJobQueue.size());
                        rowOffset += ExportManagerConstants.DATA_TRANSFER_BATCH_SIZE;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Print Job Queue is full, waiting for Consumer thread to clear.");
                        this.printerJobQueue.wait();
                    }
                }
            }           
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        } finally {
            try {
                if(null != rs) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if(null != stmt) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
                if(null != pStmt) {
                    pStmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
        ExportManager.setProducerCompleted(true);
    }
}
```

Consumer Class :-

```
public class CassandraPrintJobConsumer implements Runnable {
    private Cluster cluster = null;
    private Session session = null; 
    private BlockingQueue<PrintJobDAO> printerJobQueue = null;

    public CassandraPrintJobConsumer(BlockingQueue<PrintJobDAO> printerJobQueue) throws CassandraClientException {
        this.printerJobQueue = printerJobQueue;     
        cluster = Cluster.builder().withPort(9042).addContactPoint("http://cassandrahost").build();
    }

    public void run() {
        int printJobConsumed = 0;
        int batchInsertCount = 1;
        if(cluster.isClosed()) {
            connect();
        }
        session = cluster.connect();
        PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare(CassandraClientConstants.INSERT_PRINT_JOB_DATA);
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
        synchronized (this.printerJobQueue) {
            while(true) {
                if(!this.printerJobQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    for(int i = 1; i <= ExportManagerConstants.DATA_TRANSFER_BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
                        PrintJobDAO printJob = printerJobQueue.poll();
                        batch.add(ps.bind(printJob.getJobID(), printJob.getUserID(), printJob.getType(), printJob.getGpDate(), printJob.getDateTimes(),
                                printJob.getAppName(), printJob.getPrintedPages(), printJob.getSavedPages(), printJob.getPrinterID(), printJob.getWorkstationID(),
                                printJob.getPrintedCost(), printJob.getSavedCost(), printJob.getSourcePrinterID(), printJob.getSourcePrinterPrintedCost(),
                                printJob.getJcID(), printJob.getCoverageC(), printJob.getCoverageM(), printJob.getCoverageY(), printJob.getCoverageK(),
                                printJob.getCoverageTotal(), printJob.getPagesAnalyzed()));
                        printJobConsumed++;                 
                    }
                    session.execute(batch);
                    System.out.println("After Batch - " + batchInsertCount + ", record insert count : " + printJobConsumed);
                    batchInsertCount++;
                    this.printerJobQueue.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Print Job Queue is empty, nothing to export.");
                    try {
                        this.printerJobQueue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.err.println(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
                    }
                }
                if(ExportManager.isProducerCompleted() && this.printerJobQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manager Class :-

```
public class ExportManager {
    private static boolean isInitalized = false;
    private static boolean producerCompleted = false;
    private static MySQLPrintJobProducer printJobProducer = null;
    private static CassandraPrintJobConsumer printJobConsumer = null;
    private static BlockingQueue<PrintJobDAO> printJobQueue = null; 

    public static boolean isProducerCompleted() {
        return producerCompleted;
    }

    public static void setProducerCompleted(boolean producerCompleted) {
        ExportManager.producerCompleted = producerCompleted;
    }

    private static void init() throws MySQLClientException, CassandraClientException {
        if(!isInitalized) {
            printJobQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<PrintJobDAO>(ExportManagerConstants.DATA_TRANSFER_BATCH_SIZE * 2);
            printJobProducer = new MySQLPrintJobProducer(printJobQueue);
            printJobConsumer = new CassandraPrintJobConsumer(printJobQueue);
            isInitalized = true;
        }
    }

    public static void exportPrintJobs() throws ExportException {
        try {
            init();
        } catch (MySQLClientException e) {
            throw new ExportException("Print Job Export failed.", e);
        } catch (CassandraClientException e) {
            throw new ExportException("Print Job Export failed.", e);
        }
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(printJobProducer);
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(printJobConsumer);
        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();
    }
}
```

TestNG class :-

```
public class TestExportManager {

  @Test
  public void testExportPrintJobs() {
      try {
        ExportManager.exportPrintJobs();
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    } catch (ExportException e) {
        Assert.fail("ExportManager.exportPrintJobs() failed.", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Assert.fail("ExportManager.exportPrintJobs() failed.", e);
    }
  }
}
```

I have also made some configuration changes by following this [link](http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/08/31/building-the-perfect-cassandra-test-environment/). Still I am getting following exception after inserting 18000 - 20000 records.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.10.80
 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during read))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:64)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:172)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:91)
    at com.incendiary.ga.client.cassandra.CassandraPrintJobConsumer.run(CassandraPrintJobConsumer.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.10.80 (com.datastax.drive
r.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during read))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:100)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$1.run(RequestHandler.java:171)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I am not able to figure out the actual reason for the issue. I could not find any exception in Cassandra system log. I am using Apache Cassandra 2.0.7 and cassandra-driver-core 2.0.1.

Comment: Seems no one has faced this issue. Still any pointer to move forward in debugging would be highly appreciated. I am kind of stuck due to this issue.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue.  I ended up having to restart my tomcat instance ( the client app runs in tomcat ) to clear the issue.  I am wondering if this might be some kind of stale connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase read time out in you driver side . By using withSocket method in this you have SocketOption class using that you can read time out .By default is read time out is 10 millisecond .